# how can I center wrap as the psd?

Tags: html, css

I want to center my wrap as the psd , but I want to see it on a larger screen maybe 2000px plus. I tried with `margin: 0 auto, margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`, but it didndt work how can I fix this isssue? this is what I got so far.

html

```
  <div class="feacture_wrap">
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <div class="square">
                           <img src="img/check.png" alt="">
                           <div class="container_text">
                              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula <span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <div class="square">
                           <img src="img/check.png" alt="">
                           <div class="container_text">
                              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula <span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <div class="square">
                           <img src="img/check.png" alt="">
                           <div class="container_text">
                              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula <span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <div class="square">
                           <img src="img/check.png" alt="">
                           <div class="container_text">
                              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</h2>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula <span>eget dolor Aenean massas</span></p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
```

css

```
.wrapper,
.blog_wrap,
.feacture_wrap,
.display_wrap
.wrap_porcentaje{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.feacture_wrap{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
}

.square {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}


.square img {
    width: 10%;
}

.container_text {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 350px;
}

.container_text h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat Black';
    color: #505a78;
}

.container_text p{
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

[wrap_psd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcmi5.jpg)
[me_wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auFPT.png)

Comment: Don't use tables for layout; uses tables for tabular data. Use CSS for layout.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `table` layout, you might want to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Change each of the `td`s to `div`s and take out the `table` and `tr`s, and add this to the parent container:

```
.feacture_wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This will allow your items to align themselves, wrap when needed, and be horizontally centered.  If you want them to be vertically aligned as well, you can use `align-items`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://beerhold.it/310/250">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```